# How to know which host is writing to a directory of HDFS？

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

There is some process which has been writing to a directory of HDFS. How to know which host or app is doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a secured HDP-Kerberos cluster and that RANGER is installed with HDFS plugin enabled, you can monitor all HDFS accesses from the Audit logs and maybe find the guilty guy. Otherwise may be in the Namenode logs in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a once off requirement, you can use monitoring tools on the actual hosts. If you have sufficiently few hosts, you can use `iotop` to see which processes are generating how much I/O. This suggestion is only applicable to Linux systems.